# VBA Selection.PasteAndFormat adding a line break

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a VBA Script that finds a named cell in Excel and pastes it in Word based on an identifier that I have in Word. I use `RegEx` to find the identifier.

The problem that I am experiencing is, whenever it pastes the value (correctly) it "presses Enter" so that it goes to the next line. It should not.

Here is the script:

```
Dim objWord, objWordDoc, RegEx, objExcel, objWorkbook, content, texts, text, Text_Name

Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\Performance Review Template Rev1.docx", False, True)
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Template Rev1.xlsm", False, True)

'The entire content of the Word Document
Set content = objWord.ActiveDocument.Content

'The Regular Expression in terms of finding the short code within the document
'Explanation
'-----------
'\[# == Escaped [# characters to indicate that the start of the search needs to be an [#
'(.*?) == The forward seach in a non greedy way that is also the return group
'\] == Escaped ] character that signals the end of the search term
RegEx.Pattern = "\[#(.*?)\]"
RegEx.Global = True

Set texts = RegEx.Execute(content)
Dim Found

For Each text In texts
    Set content = objWord.ActiveDocument.Content
    'Find the TextName that is in the short code. The Submatches property returns
    'the value of the inner return group, whereas the .Value property only returns
    'the value of the short code with the [!xxx] added
    Text_Name = text.submatches(0)
    Dim xName, xText
    Found = False
    'Search for the text through all the Named Cells in the Excel file

    objExcel.Range(Text_Name).Copy

    With content.Find
         .MatchWholeWord = True
         .Text = text.Value
         .Execute
         If .Found = True Then
            Found = True
            content.PasteAndFormat 20
         End If
    End With

    If Found = False Then
        MsgBox "Did not find Named Cell!"
    End If

    With content.Find
         .Text = text.Value
         .Execute
         If .Found = True Then
            objWord.Selection.Range.Delete
         End If
    End With     
Next

MsgBox "Completed named cells"

objWord.ActiveDocument.Close
objWord.Application.Quit

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

Like always, any help is always appreciated.

Comment: Quick fix - Selection.TypeBackspace after the paste operation

Comment: I tried. It is not working. I added it after the line `content.PasteAndFormat 20`

Comment: Try it twice, you might have a layout marker in there. Literally Selection.TypeBackspace then Selection.TypeBackspace again.

Comment: @Absinthe sorry for the delay - got pulled onto another project. got to spend some time on it this morning. i am afraid the double `Selection.TypeBackspace` is not working for me.

Comment: You can create a shell object and get handle of the open word window and use sendkeys method to press the backspace key

Comment: Can you show what your copying and where your pasting it?

Comment: also Try `content.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText`

Comment: @0m3r no luck. `content.PasteSpecial` is still adding that line break. Here is a link to a screen grab of the report. Everything in yellow is pasted in by the scrpit: http://i.imgur.com/onquC3E.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be standard behavior of copy functionality (doing it manually gives same result).
Proposed solution could be to use direct copying of content instead of using copy & paste.

Formatting is also preserved from target document.
Here is tested code (Changes marked with %%%%):

```
Dim objWord, objWordDoc, RegEx, objExcel, objWorkbook, content, texts, text, Text_Name, copiedText ' %%%% Added variable

Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\Performance Review Template Rev1.docx", False, True)
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Template Rev1.xlsm", False, True)

'The entire content of the Word Document
Set content = objWord.ActiveDocument.content

'The Regular Expression in terms of finding the short code within the document
'Explanation
'-----------
'\[# == Escaped [# characters to indicate that the start of the search needs to be an [#
'(.*?) == The forward seach in a non greedy way that is also the return group
'\] == Escaped ] character that signals the end of the search term
RegEx.Pattern = "\[#(.*?)\]"
RegEx.Global = True

Set texts = RegEx.Execute(content)
Dim Found

For Each text In texts
    Set content = objWord.ActiveDocument.content
    'Find the TextName that is in the short code. The Submatches property returns
    'the value of the inner return group, whereas the .Value property only returns
    'the value of the short code with the [!xxx] added
    Text_Name = text.submatches(0)
    Dim xName, xText
    Found = False
    'Search for the text through all the Named Cells in the Excel file

    copiedText = objExcel.Range(Text_Name).text ' %%%%
    ' %%%% Instead of objExcel.Range(Text_Name).Copy

    With content.Find
         .MatchWholeWord = True
         .text = text.Value
         .Execute
         If .Found = True Then
            Found = True
            .Parent.text = copiedText ' %%%%
            ' %%%% Instead of content.PasteAndFormat 20
         End If
    End With

    If Found = False Then
        MsgBox "Did not find Named Cell!"
    End If

    With content.Find
         .text = text.Value
         .Execute
         If .Found = True Then
            objWord.Selection.Range.Delete
         End If
    End With
Next

MsgBox "Completed named cells"

objWord.ActiveDocument.Close
objWord.Application.Quit

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```